# I am running pytest on cmd and i'm getting AssertionError

Tags: python, python-3.x, cmd, pytest

So this is the code I am testing:

```
def test_sum():
    
    test_list=[10,20,30,40,50]

    result=sum(test_list)

    assert result == 150
```

The error I get:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.19041.630]
(c) 2020 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\97155>python -m pytest
================================================= test session starts =================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.7.4, pytest-6.1.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: C:\Users\97155
collected 0 items / 1 error

======================================================= ERRORS ========================================================
____________________________________________ ERROR collecting test session ____________________________________________
AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py:310: in from_call
    result = func()  # type: Optional[TResult]
AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\runner.py:340: in <lambda>
    call = CallInfo.from_call(lambda: list(collector.collect()), "collect")
AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\main.py:684: in collect
    for direntry in visit(str(argpath), self._recurse):
AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\pathlib.py:570: in visit
    yield from visit(entry.path, recurse)
AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\pathlib.py:570: in visit
    yield from visit(entry.path, recurse)
AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\pathlib.py:570: in visit
    yield from visit(entry.path, recurse)
AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\_pytest\pathlib.py:566: in visit
    entries = sorted(os.scandir(path), key=lambda entry: entry.name)
E   PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\97155\\AppData\\Local\\Application Data'
=============================================== short test summary info ===============================================
ERROR  - PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied: 'C:\\Users\\97155\\AppData\\Local\\Application Data'
!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!! Interrupted: 1 error during collection !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
================================================== 1 error in 0.27s ===================================================
```

I tried running the code using the commands (python -m pytest) and (pytest). However, I still get the same error.

Comment: Please do not post screenshots with code or errors: they are hard to search for, they might eventually disappear and, depending on the size, it can consume many bytes in people internet plans. Edit the question and past the actual error text.

BTW: I just copied the code on my computer and successfully executed it with `pytest`

Comment: If I understand you error, it has nothing to do with the code you posted

Answer (score 1):

The reason pytest is crashing here is you're running it from the root of your home directory and some folders in the home directory have special permissions

when pytest starts (with no configuration / no arguments) it attempts to recurse to detect tests -- meaning it will try and visit every file / folder from your working directory downwards

in your case, it tries to list on `'C:\\Users\\97155\\AppData\\Local\\Application Data'` which is not generically allowed on windows I guess?

I'd suggest making a subdirectory in your home directory and do work inside there, I use `workspace` for example

---

disclaimer: I'm one of the pytest core devs

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, you should delve into the documentation for the library you are trying to learn. The documentation for `pytest` can be found [here](https://docs.pytest.org/en/stable/getting-started.html#create-your-first-test).

You aren't executing `pytest` correctly from the command line. There are a few steps to executing `pytest` assertions:

1. Define your test functions and use an assertion statement using python's `assert` (which you have already done)
2. Change directories to the directory that houses the `.py` file that contains your tests
3. Execute pytest using `pytest test_file.py`

Comment: D:\Python39>pytest test_sum.py
=========================================================================== test session starts ===========================================================================
platform win32 -- Python 3.9.0, pytest-6.1.2, py-1.9.0, pluggy-0.13.1
rootdir: D:\Python39
plugins: cov-2.10.1
collected 0 items

========================================================================== no tests ran in 0.03s =========================================================================          (This is what I get)

Comment: You're running the script from inside the directory that contains `test_sum.py` right?

Comment: Yes, I am running it from the same directory.

Comment: And the function `test_sum` is in `test_sum.py`?

Comment: yes, the function test_sum is in test_sum.py